# Problem with Case_when function to recode new variable

Tags: r, tidyverse, case

I am quite new to R and dont understand whats wrong with my code.
I have a dataframe `jungmodell` and  want to create a variable out of two other variables, `parteisympathie` and `Parteinah`.

`Parteinah` has expressions from -9, -8 and 1-35.
`Parteisympathie` has expressions from -9, -8-, -7 and 1-3.

Only the people that answered the question from `Parteinah` with 2-35, where asked the question `parteisympathie`.

The ones who answered with 1, -8, -9 on `Parteinah` were coded as -7 on `parteisympathie`.

What I want to do is create a variable `Identifikationsskala`, which uses the cases that have  "1", "2" and "3"  from `parteisympathie` and the ones that have "1" from `Parteinah`, so that I don't include the -8 or -9 (which are the people that answered with "I dont know" or refused to answer).

I also want to recode the values, so that 1 from `parteisympathie` becomes 4, 2 becomes 3, 3 becomes 2 and the 1 from `Parteinah` stays 1.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work. There isn't a error message and R is running the code, but the values of `Identifikationsskala` dont change.

```
jungmodell <- jungmodell %>%  mutate(Identifikationsskala = Parteinah)  

jungmodell %>% mutate(Identifikationsskala = case_when(jungmodell$Parteinah == 1 ~ 1
                      ,(jungmodell$Parteinah >= 2) & (jungmodell$parteisympathie == 3) ~ 2, 
                      (jungmodell$Parteinah >= 2) & (jungmodell$parteisympathie == 2) ~ 3,
                      (jungmodell$Parteinah >= 2) & (jungmodell$parteisympathie == 1) ~ 4, TRUE ~ -9))
```

It would be awesome if someone could help me.
Thanks so much,
Franca

Answer (score 3):

Not tested but the appropriate code should be:

```
library(dplyr)

jungmodell %>% 
  mutate(Identifikationsskala = case_when(Parteinah == 1 ~ 1 ,
                                          Parteinah >= 2 & parteisympathie == 3 ~ 2, 
                                          Parteinah >= 2 & parteisympathie == 2 ~ 3, 
                                          Parteinah >= 2 & parteisympathie == 1 ~ 4, 
                                          TRUE ~ -9))
```

Comment: Hi Tarjae, thanks for your answer. I tried the code and R is running it, but it won't create a new variable in my dataframe. There is also no error message...

Comment: I am really clueless here... instead of adding a variable to the dataframe the console goes into grey text and says that it is creating a tibble. But I cant look at the tibble anywhere and the dataframe remains the same....

Comment: @franca122 you just need to assign the output i.e. `jungmodell <- jungmodell %>% ...`